# cat: /proc/1/comm: File not found

Tags: linux, shiny-server

I'm trying to install shiny server on my machine but I run into the following issue.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
Building data structures... Done
Building data structures... Done

    Shiny Server
     Shiny Server is a server program from RStudio, Inc. that makes Shiny applications available over the web. Shiny is a web application framework for the R statistical computation language.
    Wollen Sie das Software-Paket installieren? [j/N]:j
    Vormals nicht ausgewähltes Paket shiny-server wird gewählt.
    (Lese Datenbank ... 61026 Dateien und Verzeichnisse sind derzeit installiert.)
    Vorbereitung zum Entpacken von shiny-server-1.4.2.786-amd64.deb ...
    Entpacken von shiny-server (1.4.2.786) ...
    shiny-server (1.4.2.786) wird eingerichtet ...
    Creating user shiny
    cat: /proc/1/comm: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
    /var/lib/dpkg/info/shiny-server.postinst: 73: test: =: unexpected operator
    grep: /etc/init/shiny-server.conf: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
    Adding LANG to /etc/init.d/shiny-server, setting to de_AT.UTF-8
```

I'm not even sure what /proc/1/comm is and how I can fix this. Any suggestions?

Here is some system Info:

```
cat /proc/version
Linux version 2.6.32-5-amd64 (Debian 2.6.32-48squeeze6) (jmm@debian.org) (gcc version 4.3.5 (Debian 4.3.5-4) ) #1 SMP Tue May 13 16:34:35 UTC 2014
```

Comment: I would suggest to ask the RStudio support.

Comment: Thanks. I already posted this in their google group, but I didn't receive any answer yet so I tried it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

/proc/$PID/comm is only available in Linux 2.6.33 and later.